# In-app cyclic photo tile for windows phone

Tags: c#, xaml, windows-phone-8, tile

I am trying to create an **in-app** tile like the image below (groups), with images flipping on the tile. I have gone through the `HubTile` but couldn't find. Which WP control would help to create such type of tile effect. Plus, will data binding of images be possible for the tile `ImageSource` ?

P.S. - This is not a live tile. I want the tile within the app.

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have you tried ImageTile control [from Coding4Fun toolkit](http://coding4fun.codeplex.com/)?

A detailed article on how to use it can be found [on GeekChamp](http://www.geekchamp.com/articles/getting-started-with-the-coding4fun-toolkit-imagetile-control).

Answer (score 0):

The [Windows Phone Toolkit](http://phone.codeplex.com/) has a free `HubTile` control that can be used within your application. There are also commercial alternatives such as Telerik's [HubTile](http://www.telerik.com/products/windows-phone/overview/all-controls/hubtile.aspx).

Comment: I mentioned that I have gone through the `HubTile`. Please provide with the detail/xaml example, if you can, which shows "image flipping" tile effect.

Comment: looking at the screenshots for Telerik's HubTile, I can see it flipping as you describe.